# How to modify width of standard dialog form sharepoint 2010

Tags: css, list-definition, list-form, modal-dialog

Please, help me!

I need to modify width of standard dialog form for adding element into library.

If I click to ribbon button for adding element, form opened with width=402px:

```
<div class="ms-dlgContent" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialogTitleSpan"  tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 1505; display: block; width: 402px; height: 294px; left: 430px; top: 104px; "></div>
```

If I click to button under all elements of current library, form opened with width=1032px:

```
<div class="ms-dlgContent" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialogTitleSpan" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 1505; display: block; width: 1032px; height: 267px; left: 115px; top: 273px; "></div>
```

I can't understand, what I need to do for opening in the second case form with width=402px.

Maybe need enter some code in Upload.aspx? (this form generate automatically) I guess, this page open for creating new element, because schema.xml for my list definition contain this code:

```
<Forms>
   <Form Type="DisplayForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/DispForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
   <Form Type="EditForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/EditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
   <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Forms/Upload.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

But if modify this part of Upload.aspx (add .ms-dglContent class), it doesn't help me:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
padding: 8px;
border: none;
}
.ms-dglContent {
    width:402px!important;
}
</style>
</asp:Content>
```

If I modify css files:

```
.ms-dglContent {width:402px!important;}
```

it modify all dialog forms, but in my case is unacceptable.

I would be grateful for any attempt to help!

Answer (score 2):

@Kate Ponomareva
sorry for the delayed reply (wasn't online), follow below steps to add html form webpart

1 : through SPD, create your required forms for the respective list and set them as default or you could use the default form itself

2 : go to your sharepoint site, click on the list from View All Site content or Quick Launch

3 : in top ribbon click on **List** (List Tools)

4 : towards right you will see option as **Form Web Parts**, click on it, the three forms will be listed there [New Form, Display Form, Edit Form]

5 : select the one on which you want to increase the width/height

6 : it will open in edit mode, click on **Add a Web Part**

7 : Click on Forms [Categories] => HTML Form Web Part

8 : After adding the HTML Form Web Part, click on Edit Webpart

9 : Click on Source Editor, Remove all code from it and put a empty HTML table with width and height as per your requirement
ex. to increase width

`<TABLE WIDTH="800px">
<TR><TD></TD></TR>
</TABLE>`

10: save the form and check out your respective modal by clicking on the same in your list view

Comment: +1 This makes a lot more sense; thanks for coming back and clarifying. Unfortunately It's standard practice to edit extra details into your existing answer: SE won't let me undo my earlier downvote without an edit to that answer.

Comment: @StuartPegg , that's fine!
there are so many things on SharePoint which are still not into any documentation or eBook!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Designer 2010, turns out you just go to Data View Tools > Web Part > Width, and type in the new width of the form. In the code, it looks like:

`<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" ......   Width="1000">`

Answer (score -1):

insert a html form webpart into the add form , include code into the same of a blank html table setting the width as per your preference.

Comment: Great idea! but.. How I can insert a html form webpart into the add form?

Comment: -1 I'm afraid at the moment this answer doesn't seem to make any sense: Web parts cannot be added to the dialog forms by default.

Comment: @StuartPegg I'm afraid you didn't had the idea of how to do it that's why it didn't make any sense to you, my first reply was for a person who had enough idea on SharePoint list forms and ribbon controls, do not come to a conclusion so early!